# Destroying objects of Java classes from JRuby

Tags: java, jruby

We can create objects of Java classes from JRuby using .new method.
But is there any way to manually destroy/deallocate/call destructor of that object in JRuby?

Answer (score 1):

Given that JRuby runs inside a JVM, there is no way of saying "free an object". Even Ruby does not have a notion explicit "free" operator. That is managed by the VM.

What is it that you are trying to achieve?

A big (advertised at least) advantage of using a language that runs in a managed environment (like a VM) is so that, well, its managed. Dealing with garbage is one of them.